# Vue Transition Group Animation - start v-move only after v-leave finishes

Tags: vue.js, css-animations, vue-transitions, vuejs-transition-group

I would like to have the following flow:

5 items on a stack of notifications.

1 item is poped, so it enters on v-leave state, while the other 4 items don't animate at all. After item enters on v-leave state, the other 4 items animate to their new position.

```
.leave-active,
.fade-enter-active {
  animation-duration: 750ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.fade-move {
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.